# Handbrake cable for Toyota Corolla 1993

Tags: toyota, corolla, handbrake

I have a 1993 Toyota Corolla, it needs a new handbrake cable, but I haven't been able to find one to buy.

So, are there any other handbrake cable options (like a different Corolla year perhaps) that can be used instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see, there are two cables; rear left and rear right.  I'm afraid I do not know if they very by location but in the UK, for Right Hand Drive, Pagid appear to manufacture both.

The following ebay links show a list of (six pages worth) compatible vehicles;

[Rear Left](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Pagid-Rear-Left-Handbrake-Cable-Toyota-Corolla-E12-E11-E10-1992-1997-/330880382628#vi-ilComp)

[Rear Right](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Pagid-Rear-Right-Handbrake-Cable-Toyota-Corolla-E12-E11-E10-1992-1997-/301287810389#vi-ilComp)

I would personally be surprised if the LHD versions are any different.